# B2C Custom Policy Nested SubJourney

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The Microsoft documentation on subjourneys state the following: A sub journey is called only from a user journey, it shouldn't call another sub journey. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/subjourneys#user-journey-branching)

From a development point of view it would be good to split reusable steps into subjouneys and call as required which is exactly how MS structure their policies, this is an extract of base-v1

```
  <SubJourney Id="TotpFactor-Verify" Type="Call">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
        <JourneyList>
          <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="SetTotpInitialValue" />
        </JourneyList>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
```

The base-v1 entire setup is small reusable subjourneys that are referenced from others.

Do we know if this statement in the documentation is out of date or it's not support for customer custom policies?